# load more data using endAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am initially loading the last 5 items from my database node using `limitToLast(5)` as follows:

```
var myData = [];
var firstKey;

var fetchInitialData(category){
    firebase.database().ref(category).orderByKey().limitToLast(5).once('value' , function(snap){
        addDatToArray(snap);
    });
}

fetchInitialData('myCategory');

var addDatToArray = function(snap){
    snap.forEach(function(child){
        myData.push(child.val());
        if(!firstKey){
            firstKey = child.key;
        }
    });
}
```

I have a load more button which fetches 5 more items and pushes it to `myData[]`. Since I am storing the `firstKey` in the initial fetch I pass it to `endAt()` as follows:

```
var fetchMoreData(category){
    firebase.database().ref(category).orderByKey().endAt(firstKey).limitToLast(5).once('value' , function(snap){
        firstKey = null;
        addDatToArray(snap);
    });
}
```

It works fine but the problem is since I am fetching more and limiting data using `endAt()` and `endAt()` includes the item at the ending pint also. So for every load more data one item is duplicated in the `myData` array.

To be descriptive consider the folowimg example:

**my data structure**

```
----category
    --item1
    --item2
    --item3
    --item4
    --item5
    --item6
    --item7
    --item8
    --item9
    --item10
```

**1.** on initial fetch i fetch the last 5 items which are items 6-10 and the `firstKey` is set to `item6`.
items displayed to user are

```
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10
```

**2.** on load more fetch `firstKey` which is `item6` is passed to `endAt()` and since `endAt()` is inclusive it also fetches `item6` and pushes it to `myData[]`

items displayed to user are

```
item6
item7
item8
item9
item10

item5
item4
item3
item2
item6//fetched again
```

How to overcome this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding data to the array, you could just ignore the child if it matches the key of your endAt query? So your `addDatToArray` method would take one more argument, such as:

```
var addDatToArray = function(snap, ignoreKey){
    snap.forEach(function(child){
        if(child.key != ignoreKey) {
            myData.push(child.val());
        }
        if(!firstKey){
            firstKey = child.key;
        }
    });
}
```

From the docs of [firebase.database.Query#endAt](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endAt):

> The ending point is inclusive, so children with exactly the specified value will be included in the query.

Therefore, you'll need to account for that by adjusting `limitToLast` by +1 and then discarding the duplicate result.

Comment: good idea but that would technicallly mean i am fetchimg only 4 instead of 5... where i want 5 items fetched

Comment: I see, I guess you could then use `limitToLast(6)` for the `fetchMoreData` method to get one more result?

Comment: Yup i'll try. Thanks, but there might be a better solution. If you find it out please edit the answer....:)

Comment: It does seem hacky but the [`firebase.database.Query#endAt`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endAt) method is always inclusive, so children with exactly the specified value will be included in the query. Therefore, you have to account for that and load +1 more result, then discard the one you don't need. I've added this clarification to the answer.

Comment: Great answer @Grimthorr!